# != OR <> OR NOT IN Operators Supports in ODATA?

Tags: salesforce, odata, informatica

i have the query for external object named as test__x.

I am writing the query to get the data using OData 4.0 in external data sourse by applying the `NOT EQUAL TO` logic with `!=` OR `<>` OR `NOT IN` operators then facing an error stating as below.

**SQL:**

```
select id,status__c  from current_year_order_summary__x where status__c NOT IN('C') LIMIT 2000
```

**Error:**

> "Error received from the external system: 500:
>   com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.runtime.exception.ReadException:
>   java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.14]
>   [Error 3707] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error, expected something like a
>   'SUCCEEDS' keyword or a 'MEETS' keyword or a
>   'PRECEDES' keyword or an 'IN' keyword or a
>   'CONTAINS' keyword between the word 'status__c ' and
>   '|'."

Comment: looks like syntax error to me. So, can you try simple SQL like this select id,status__c  from current_year_order_summary__x. Then add where clause to see if its working. BTW, have you fired this SQL in the database and got success?

Comment: I have tried different scenarios where as it is working if we give the = opearator and only != operator is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In OData 4, the equality and inequality [operators](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc371341751) are `eq` and `ne`.

Comment: Yes but in salesforce we will mentioned three operators and odata will convert into the ne.as of now it is converting into ne but we are getting the error .we have tested with external db and ne is working from their end also

Comment: My expectation would odata in not able to converting this into